# What kind of parity is this? (5x5)

Tags: rubiks-cube

I was just solving my 5x5 cube as always, but at the end I got this configuration and haven't found anything regarding this kind of parity. I am pretty sure all squares are correctly placed and no twists are there.

Before I got the edge parity in 5x5, then I used my 4x4 parity algorithm taking 1-2 as left and right sides respectively. This was the result. I am pretty much confused to how this happened?

The configuration is:

```
whole solved except middle edges on O-Y, Y-R, R-W are y-r, w-r, o-y respectively with r-r-y on top(rotating ccw).
```

Images are included for reference.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The second and last pictures are identical.

Comment: I was just taking snaps while rotating the cube, so it would be in sequence. I guess I came back to that image over a cycle. But anyways, What do you think is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a single flipped edge piece.

This renders your cube unsolvable: If you ignore everything except the corners, centers, and edge middle pieces, you get a 3x3x3 cube, and on that cube, a single piece flip is definitely unsolvable.

Here's how to get from a solved cube to a situation that is one edge piece flip away from your cube's pattern. The red-yellow edge piece in the middle of the orange-yellow edge is the one flipped piece.

[image]

Doing the moves in reverse order should bring your cube to within one edge piece flip from being solved, but unless I'm mistaken, that's as close as you are going to get without taking the cube apart. (Flipping the center piece of an edge should be a pretty easy task, luckily.)